# Why gobject has install_properties method?

Tags: gobject

I am following gobject tutorial and I see there is one method which is install_proprties() which installs properties which later can be used to by set_properties and get_properties. My question is why do we need install_properties instead can we have fields directly in instance structure like in C++ or Java ?

Answer (score 1):

GObject is an object oriented framework on top of C; this means that it has to provide functionality on top of a smaller language, without the syntactic sugar of higher level languages, such as C++ or Java.

In the case of properties, GObject has to define "named fields" at run time, to allow introspection — i.e. the ability to query an object type for its capabilities — as well as generic access and change notification. These named fields do not necessarily map to a field in the instance structure: they can be read-only or write-only; they can be computed on the fly; they can be used only at construction time.

Other languages may have these capabilities as well, but they are usually exposed through the language's own syntax; this cannot happen in GObject/C.